# "Я разморозил радиатор..."

Tags: этимология

Если в систему охлаждения автомобиля залить воду и оставить на морозе, то согласно законам физики, вода замерзнет и "разорвет" двигатель или радиатор. Но... автомобилисты в таком случае говорят: "я разморозил радиатор", т.е называют процесс, как раз обратный произошедшему. Интересно происхождение этого термина. У кого нибудь есть идеи?

Answer (score 1):

Вообще "разморозить трубы, бочки, даже шампанское" может значить то же самое. Не радиатором единым. Происхождение понятно, переосмысление "**раз**орвать **морозом**" (или "от мороза"). Вряд ли можно принять нормативным для всякого стиля, но как разговорное давно уже стало общепринятым.